# li clickable but with rel - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery prettyPhoto to display an overlay window.

On my page I have an li with a link and image, I want the whole li to be clickable BUT the link is #, so it's rel doing the work.

```
<a href="#inline-'.$i.'" rel="prettyPhoto[inline]">'.preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$vimeo->title).'</a>
```

Below is my jQuery, any ideas?

```
$(function() {
    $('.clickable').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href") + $(this).find("a").attr("rel");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Argh. I wish people would stop abusing `rel` to describe things that are not relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend against trying to make the `<li>` clickable. If you can't wrap some element (like an `<li>` or a `<td>`) in an anchor, you can make the anchor fill the whole area of the element with CSS: [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3fJk/). (You can probably find less rough ways to do that on ALA or such.) Then just intercept the click event on the link.

Also, as Quentin said, don't repurpose `rel` or other attributes; you can use [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) as a "clean" alternative.